# AWS Amplify - Does it run PHP scripts?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, phpmailer, aws-amplify

My website has a contact us page with a HTML form that submit POST's to a local PHP script that uses `PHPMailer` to send an email.  My question is, if I move my website to AWS Amplify, will it still work?  What version of PHP do they use?  I posted a question on their forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=333012), but have gotten no response.

[image]

Comment: Yes! [The simplest server configuration for your AWS Amplify/Cognito App](https://eu-galioto.medium.com/the-simplest-server-configuration-for-your-aws-amplify-cognito-app-a074c01c743d)